# Не отображает изображение в GitHub Pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages

На локальной машине все работает, проверял через

> Open Server и LiveServer от VSCode.

Но при загрузке на Git Hub Pages изображение перестаёт отображаться.
Изображение добавляю в CSS

```
.header {
    height: 700px;
    background: url(/img/photo.JPG) center center/cover no-repeat;
    padding-left: 40%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

> Так же пробовал и url(./img/photo.JPG) и url(img/photo.JPG)

В HTML добавляю в тег

```
<section class="header">
```

Comment: Вангую несовпадение регистра символов. Или неправильный путь

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался прост
перед директорией необходимо добавить две точки

```
background: url(../img/photo.JPG)
```